# Google map doesnt appear in a model popup wuth angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I'm using angular 4 and i want to use google map in model popup, but it doesnt appear, i dont know why, heres the code :

component.ts:

```
showChildModal(): void { //Mehtod to fire the popup
this.parentModal.show();
 }

ngOnInit() {
let mapProp = {
  center: { lat: 30.42018, lng: -9.5981500 },

  zoom: 5,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #parentModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      div class="modal-dialog modal-width">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
               <div class="panel-body">
               <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:380px;"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and heres what i get :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtIK5.png)

Comment: More code is needed to address your issue.

Comment: ok i wille add some code.

Comment: its done, you can check @PHPglue

Comment: How do you call `ngOnInit`? Where is opening event?

Comment: when i click a button to open the popup, the showChildModal(): void { //Mehtod to fire the popup
this.parentModal.show();
 }  is fired